# How to retrieve file name and module name in Abstract Syntax Tree?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, flake8

I'm looking a way I can grasp the file name and module being checked by flake8 plugins so that I could apply my own convention rule to them.

I tried:

```
    # To check module
    def visit_Module(self, node):

        print node.__dict__

        self.generic_visit(node)
```

But it does not return the correct object I was looking for. By using `__name__`, `__package__`, or `__file__` it return the plugin file and module instead of file name and module being checked.

What is a method in Python AST that could return the file name and module name being checked by flake8? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Python AST does not store this information, if you need it you should ask flake8 for the `filename` parameter or something along those lines.

Comment: thanks. I'm aware of that. How about getting those information by AST? I saw flake8 plugin doing that as here https://pypi.org/project/flake8-filename/, but I need to develop that from my own. Thanks.

Comment: Again you can *not* get that information through the AST. That's not possible, the information doesn't exist there. And again, you *can* ask flake8 for the filename (and a bunch of other things) separately from the AST. If you look a the code [that's exactly what flake8-filename does](https://github.com/rcbops/flake8-filename/blob/5718d4af394c318d376de7434193543e0da45651/flake8_filename/__init__.py#L56-L66), it asks for the `filename` parameter and works with that, not the AST.